# sed time and http request from access logs

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I am looking at access logs which have plenty entries such as:

```
localhost_access_log.2012-05-07.txt:129.223.57.10 - - [07/May/2012:00:02:11 +0000] 2434 "POST /maker/www/jsp/opp/OpportunityForm.do HTTP/1.1" 302 - "https://dm2.myjones.com/maker/www/jsp/opp/Opportunity.jsp?screenDisplay={0}&forecastIcon={1}" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.2; MS-RTC LM 8)"
```

the number after the datetime stamp is the execution time and the string in quotes is the URL.

I wish to just sed, the URL and the response time and have them in the format

```
URL, response time
```

e.g.

```
POST /maker/www/jsp/opp/OpportunityForm.do HTTP/1.1,  2434
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed`:

```
sed 's/^[^]]\+\] \([[:digit:]]\+\) \("[^"]\+"\).*/\2,\1/' inputfile
```

Perl:

```
perl -lne 'print "$2,$1" if /.*? (\d+) (".*?")/'
```

Comment: Move the quotes outside the parentheses if you don't want to include them in the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to print 6th, 7th, 8th and 9th entries like this:

```
awk '{print $7, $8, $9, ", " $6}' <access_log>
```

Output: `"POST /maker/www/jsp/opp/OpportunityForm.do HTTP/1.1" , 2434`

`awk` by default separates fields by space. `nth` gets stored in `$n`. So in your input line:

```
$7: "POST
$8: /maker/www/jsp/opp/OpportunityForm.do
$9: HTTP/1.1"
$6: 2434
```

Comment: Thanks. Why is the $8, $9 needed? And is there anyway to the get the comma in the output? Reason is I need to create CSV file with times. Thanks.

Comment: @dublintech, What platform are you on. For me this works on both Linux and Mac. What was the exact command that you used?

Comment: Sorry. I removed that comment. I am on windows and using gnu awk. When I do gawk instead of awk - all is fine.

Comment: @dublintech, edited my answer to output comma. Also explanation on fields.